# How to store array values of type String[] and BigInteger[] into shared preference inside for loop

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am receiving the following array values in a for loop:

```
String[] array1 = new String[""];
BigInteger array2 = new BigInteger[10];

for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
array1[i] //of type string array
array2[i] //of type bigint array

//Now inside same loop i want to store and retrieve those values of array
from shared preferences. Can someone tell me how to store values of array
into preference which are of type String[] and BigInteger[] 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store whole array data in shared preferences then you need to take shared preferences key array as same size of your array.

**OR**

You can append all array data with comma separator in one string object & store in shared preferences and when you get data then split string by comma.

**Updated**

```
    String[] array1 = new String[10];
    StringBuilder array1Data = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {

        array1Data.append(array1[i]);
        array1Data.append(",");

    }

    setSharedPreferences("KEY", array1Data.toString()); // Custom method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSONArray array` for that. For insert value call `array.put(String)` or `array.put(long)`. Insert into preferences as String by calling `array.toString()`. Get from preferences - `array = new JSONArray(stringFromPreferences)`. Get value from array - `array.getString(position)` and `array.getLong(postion)`.

You can also work with `array.put(Object)` and `(String) array.get(position)`.